# Самообучение нейронных сетей

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, обучение-с-подкреплением

Можно ли использовать *правила Хебба* для обучения нейронных сетей без учителя?
Структура моей сети очень специфична, пытался сделать подобие реальной нервной системы хотя бы простейших существ - беспорядочно соединенные между собой нейроны.

*Правила Хебба* добавят моей сети нейропластичность - используемые связи будут усиливаться. Так же нейроны будут иметь шанс соединиться с рандомным нейроном, что еще больше увеличивает нейропластичность.

Если *правила Хебба* работают, то имеет ли смысл отдельные системы обучать отдельно? Один класс для зрения, другой - для зрения. После совместить, и, благодаря правилам Хебба появятся связи между отдельными частями.

Т.к. я пытаюсь сделать наиболее реалистичный симулятор нервной системы, то я решил использовать *стоханические нейроны* - для наибольшего сходства со спайковой нейронной сетью, но и чтобы не усложнять задачу. Правильный ли мой выбор?
Какие есть недостатке в моем проекте?

Был вариант сделать обучение с подкреплением, но я так и не понял как, ни примеров понятных не найду, ни по теории не получается понять.

Comment: ничего не понимаю в сетях, что причем тут c#?

Comment: Потому что на нем все реализуется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На базе правила Хебба может быть построен процесс обучения нейронной сети без учителя. Это известный факт, см. например: 
https://morphs.ru/posts/21

Про *"Один класс для зрения, другой - для зрения. После совместить, и, благодаря правилам Хебба появятся связи между отдельными частями."* не понял ничего.

Вы бы хоть рассказали, какую задачу пытаетесь учить. Если распознавание визуальных картинок - то есть сверточные сети, которые переизобретать как бы не советую.

Что есть "реалистичный симулятор нервной системы" да тем более "наиболее" - вообще загадка. Искусственные нейронные сети должны решать задачи, а не ставить цель быть на кого-то там похожими. Более того, наиболее удачные примеры ИНС как раз работают со сетью, "похожесть" которых на реальные нейронно-мозговые сети заканчиваются на названии.